# How to select first child inside first child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can i select the"Automobiles" text and the unordered list right after that.
Without changing the html code.

I tried selecting it with- nav ul li
also tried with- nav:first-child ul:first-child

```
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Automobiles
                <ul>
                    <li>812Superfast</li>
                    <li>GTC4Lusso</li>
                    <li>488GTB</li>
                    <li>488Spider</li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
   </ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by "*[selecting]...the text*"?

Comment: Actually i was trying to do so that whenever user hovers over "Automobiles", the ul right after that does something. At first i thought that the problem was with the selectors. What i tried doing --> nav ul li:hover nav ul li ul { .... }, but that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just separately define them them:

```
nav ul li, nav ul li ul {
...
}
```

Just for information: If you are able to modify the html code, you should use classes within the elements.